# how to get a boolean from ArrayList in processing

Tags: arrays, arraylist, processing

I have an `ArrayList`, "list", that contains one value, true. However, when i write:

`if (list.get(0)==true)`

I get the error "incompatible operand types Object and boolean". Is `ArrayList.get()` method always return `object`? if so, how can I get the `boolean` value?

thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your list always contains booleans I suggest you type your arraylist as boolean

```
List<Boolean> list = ArrayList<Boolean> ();
```

And now you are able to do what you want to do:

```
if (list.get(0))
```

For information:

`if (list.get(0)==true)` and `if (list.get(0))` are identical.

if you cannot use generics you can cast

```
if((Boolean) list.get(0))
{
    System.out.println("OK");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, ArrayList stores objects and it cannot know the class, unless you use generics.

So you have two options: Generics or casting every "get".

With casting:

```
if ( ((Boolean)list.get(0))==true ) { ... }
```

With generics, declare list as:

```
List<Boolean> list= new ArrayList<>();
list.add(true);

if (list.get(0)) { // list.get(0)==true is unnecesary
...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try to create a var to verify if the "if" statement will be true like this:

`for(int i = 0; i < aList.size();i++){
            match = aList.get(i).equals("Red");
            System.out.print(match);
        }`

The match variable will receive the Boolean value of this comparison.

Regards,

Otacon.